# How to apply plugins

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

I am trying to apply sonarqube plugins with gradle project but currently getting issue

startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Test\build.gradle': 31: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

```
import io.restassured.response.*



ext{
    serenity_version = "2.0.40"
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {

        classpath 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.5'
        }
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}


plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.2"
}

description = 'Example of SonarQube Scanner for Gradle Usage'
version = '1.0'

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'Example of SonarQube Scanner for Gradle Usage'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'
apply plugin: 'maven'



repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$nexus_username"
            password "$nexus_password"
        }
        url 'XXX/nexus/content/groups/private'
        url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {


    testCompile ''


    compile(

    )
}
```

Can someone please help me to sort out my issue

Comment: The message is pretty clear. It says that you have stuff *before* the `plugins` block that shouldn't be there. Read the message.

Comment: Can you please help me with the solution. I am pretty new to gradle and sonarqube